# IDA 7.5 Show the Progress from Auto Analysis?

Tags: ida

Is it possible to create a box / bar in IDA wich indicates the progress?

Comment: Sorry your question was a little confusing, can you provide more details? so maybe I can help you improve your question, because by default you can see the progress statuses on the bottom side of the IDA.

Comment: Sorry My Bad.  

Yes u can see the actual status what IDA is doing, expamble: AC 0000FF45355D3.. the address is being analyzed. But u cant see how many functions are left or how long it is expecting to analyse / how much is finished.  Maybe i am wrong and there is a way. (New to IDA)

My Question is, is there an in built function or a Plugin to see more detail where it is standing right now?

Comment: You can see the progress in the colorful thing on top the yellow arrow shows how far it got. orange arrow shows which part of the code you are viewing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the progress in the colorful thing on top the orange arrow shows how far it got. yellow arrow shows which part of the code you are viewing.

100% when the orange arrow reaches the end of the blue colorful block grey colorful thing shows strings. red colorful stuff shows functions not yet made into functions

Comment: Although this isn't strictly linear progress. In big binaries or on slow computers you'll see how the indicator jumps back and forth while analyzing the code.

Answer (score 3):

### the Progress of Autoanalysis of IDA

#### main logic

there is two `level`=`hierarchy`:

- refer [here](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/620.shtml), general total **12** `step`=`pass` for `autoanalysis`:

  - `FL:<address>` execution flow is being traced
  - `PR:<address>` a function is being created
  - `TL:<address>` a function tail is being created
  - `SP:<address>` the stack pointer is being traced
  - `AC:<address>` the address is being analyzed
  - `LL:<number>`  a signature file is being loaded
  - `L1:<address>` the first pass of FLIRT
  - `L2:<address>` the second pass of FLIRT
  - `L3:<address>` the third pass of FLIRT
  - `TP:<address>` type information is being applied
  - `FI:<address>` the final pass of autoanalysis
  - `WF:<address>` weak execution flow is being traced
- the `progress`=`percentage` of each `step`=`pass`

  - the orange arrow inside top binary bar indicated the realtime progress

#### example

- main step process

  - in `AC` step -> `AC` is step `5`, total `12` steps

    - can consider as the main process/percentage is: `5`/`12`=`41.7%`
- the detail process inside current `AC` step

  - show in figure, process is about `~45%`

    - [image]

-->>

- total process: `~46%`